# linq entityframework get result from joining tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to write a Linq that return results from joining 3 tables

there're 'Book', 'Author' Entities. 1 book can have many authors and 1 author can write many books

I want to get a 'BooksAuthors' object that has the book name and the list of author who wrote the book. My current linq is (but it return nothing, I get NullPointer exception)

```
BooksAuthors = db.tblBooks.SelectMany(
                    book => book.Authors,
                    (book, author) => new Books
                    {
                        BookID = book.BookID,
                        BookName = book.BookName,
                        Authors = book.Authors
                    }),
```

Other classes:

```
public class Author
{
    public virtual int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public virtual string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
public class Book
{
    public virtual int BookID { get; set; }
    public virtual string BookName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}


public class Books
    {
        public int BookID { get; set; }
        public string BookName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    }
public class LibraryDb : DbContext
{        
    public DbSet<Book> tblBooks { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should return a IEnumerable of type Books with a list of Authors.

```
IEnumerable<Books> x =
            db.tblBooks.Select(t => new Books {BookID = t.BookID, Authors = t.Authors, BookName = t.BookName});
```